# Discord.py specific user ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello stack overflow community!

Just wanted to ask why when If I give a specific user ID to a ban command it return me the following(The purpose of this command its just when someone with bans perms enters it w/o ping or introducing any input and only the command it gets banned, aka a mini troll ban command):

[image]

Here's the command code:

```
>     @client.command() @commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
> #async def niceroger(ctx,Member:discord.User=None): async def niceroger(ctx,Member:discord.User=None):
>     user=669680584376713259
>     username = client.get_user(user)
>     #user2=discord.get_member(669680584376713259)
>     reason = "Bye bye"
>     await ctx.guild.ban(username, reason=reason)
>     #await ctx.guild.ban(user, reason=reason)
>     #await ctx.guild.ban(Member, reason = reason)
>     await ctx.channel.send(f"Bye <@669680584376713259>")
```

Best regards,
Engineer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure to always enter the error message as just a code block instead of an image. It seems that your issue is just an `AttributeError` and that `username` has no `id`. I think the issue here is this line:

```
username = client.get_user(user)
```

According the documentation, `client.get_user(id)` will return `None` if it can't find a user with the given id. So make sure that your `user` variable is correct.

Comment: Thank you for respone, this is the error pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/eVHR58dG

Sadly, for some reason it still showing the same error? How do I set up the variable correctcly?

Comment: I think the variable is setup correctly however the id itself may be wrong. The error is occurring because `client.get_user(user)` is returning `None` and assigning to `username`. And later the code is trying to get `username.id`, however it doesn't exist because `username` is `None`. So make sure that the number assigned to `user` is correct so `client.get_user(user)` doesn't return `None`

Comment: Sorry to disturb again, just retrying to remember everything from my python basic course, now i added de > client.get_user(user) and now its a different story. Would you mind to do an example code or refer to one so I can see how it works: https://pastebin.com/FLeVRi2V

Comment: No worries. Are you sure that `669680584376713259` is the correct id. Because if so, I don't see why your issue persists. I took your code from that pastebin linked and updated it [here](https://pastebin.com/vrmfh4NN). Not a 100% sure if it works but give it a shot. If it doesn't then I think the `id` is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that made me progress a lot and we just passed a bit, now i found the issue and is that the line "member = ctx.message.guild.get_member(user_id)" never manages to find ANY discord ID, neither mine, neither the provided one from an ALT acc. Is this bc we are not setting the field "user_id = 669680584376713259" correctly?

Comment: Hm that's odd. Okay try this `user = client.fetch_user(id)`. This will return a `User` instead of a `Member` so you ban them like this `await ctx.guild.ban(user, reason=reason)`. The `user_id` is set correctly, as long as it is an `int` it is set correctly. The value itself could be incorrect but it seems you already clarified that.

Comment: Hmm, i changed the bot response before the "ban" gets applied to see if it responds with the user by mentioning it but it outputs something that i never seen? Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/fj5VuZcf

Comment: Oh I apologize, my mistake. It should be `await client.fetch_user(id)`, it is a coroutine so it must be awaited.

Comment: It worked, thank you Roopesh and apologies for the disturbance!!

Comment: No worries, good luck!